# Posts from multiblt categories but featured image only in the first one, the rest to have the post title only

Tags: categories

I'm having difficulties to set the featured image only in the first post of each category and the rest to displayed with the post title only. I manage until now to display the latest post from each category with thumbnail but i cannot find the way to make the first post only with thumbnail and the rest with titles. is there a solution? Here is my code:

```
                <?php
                    //get terms (category ids 11,2,33,34), then display one post in each term
                    $taxonomy = 'category';//  e.g. post_tag, category
                    $param_type = 'category__in'; //  e.g. tag__in, category__in
                    $term_args=array(
                      'include' => '4,5,6,7',
                      'orderby' => 'name',
                      'order' => 'ASC'
                    );
                    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
                    if ($terms) {
                      foreach( $terms as $term ) {
                        $args=array(
                          "$param_type" => array($term->term_id),
                          'post_type' => 'post',
                          'post_status' => 'publish',
                          'posts_per_page' => 1,
                          'caller_get_posts'=> 1
                          );
                        $my_query = null;
                        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                          //Panikos Remove   echo 'Latest Post in '.$taxonomy .' '.$term->name;
                          while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="post_home_main">


                            <!--  Add timthumb to post featured image -->
                            <?php
                            $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($image_id);
                            if ($image_url) {
                            ?>
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $image_url; ?>&w=196&h=115&q=1000" alt="<?php the_title();?>" />
                             <!--  // Add timthumb to post featured image -->
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/no-image.jpg'; ?>" alt="No image available" class="panikosule" />
                            <?php } ?>


                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
                            </div>
                           <?php
                          endwhile;
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
                    ?>





    <span class="arrow"></span> </div>
```

Comment: Please check your spelling (esp. the title).

Answer (score 1):

### General notes

1. 1<sup>st</sup> of all: You don't have to use the (imho crappy) TimThumb thingy. There're much better things like my (freely available, open source) [»Dynamic image resize« plugin](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Dynamic-Image-Resize).
2. 2<sup>nd</sup> (and afaik), you can do this with on board stuff, like [`get_image_tag()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_image_tag/) in your case.
3. 3<sup>rd</sup>: Don't throw that many variables into the global namespace. If you really think you can't work around it: prefix them with a unique string like `wpse69602_`.
4. 4<sup>th</sup> Try to write clean code with lots of white space. This helps you spotting errors like this: `'include' => '4,5,6,7'`. Hint: Most of those functions take *arrays* and not special-character separated strings.

### Your cleaned up code

The kool thing I used to identify the number of the currently looped post isn't a `$flag`. It's a part of the `$wp_query` object: The `current_post`, which is a flag already set by WordPress.

```
<div class="container">
<?php
$terms = get_terms(
     'category'
    ,array(
         'include' => array( '4,5,6,7' )
        ,'orderby' => 'name'
        ,'order'   => 'ASC'
    )
);
if ( ! empty( $terms ) )
{
    foreach( $terms as $term ) 
    {
        $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
             'category__in'     => array( $term->term_id )
            ,'post_type'        => 'post'
            ,'post_status'      => 'publish'
            ,'posts_per_page'   => 1
            ,'caller_get_posts' => 1
        ) );
        if ( $my_query->have_posts() )
        {
            while ( $my_query->have_posts() )
            {
                $my_query->the_post();
                ?>

                <div class="post_home_main">

                <!-- Show the posts featured image -->
                <?php
                if ( 1 <= $my_query->current_post )
                {
                    if ( $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) )
                    {
                        echo get_image_tag(
                             get_post_thumbnail_id()
                            ,__( 'Featured Image', 'your_textdomain' )
                            ,get_the_title()
                            ,'none'
                             // Check your image sizes and adjust this one
                            ,'thumb'
                        );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory().'/images/no-image.jpg'; ?>" alt="No image available" class="panikosule" />
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 

                </div>

                <?php
            } // endwhile;
        }
    }
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
<span class="arrow"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: i get syndax error where it says: ,'none'  and  <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory().'/images/no-image.jpg'; ?>" alt="No image available" class="panikosule" />

Comment: @user22591 Forgot a quote - fixed

Answer (score 0):

Just before the `while ($my_query->have_posts())` add `$flag = false;`, then wrap your featured image code in another if condition like this

```
if( !$flag ) {

$flag = true;

// put all you featured image code here

}
```

Now change the `post_per_page` parameter to higher number. The image code will only be executed the first time the loop runs for each category

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
if( !$flag ) {
    $flag = true;
?>

                        <!--  Add timthumb to post featured image -->
                        <?php
                        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($image_id);
                        if ($image_url) {
                        ?>
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $image_url; ?>&w=196&h=115&q=1000" alt="<?php the_title();?>" />
                         <!--  // Add timthumb to post featured image -->
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/no-image.jpg'; ?>" alt="No image available" class="panikosule" />
                        <?php } ?>


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Mridul. But i think i ;m doing domething wrong with the php tags. Im getting an error where is the  if( !$flag ) {

                                $flag = true;

Comment: i upadated the answer above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kaiser and Mridul for your reply. I manage to achieve what i want with this code:

```
<div class="categorys_box">
   <!-- Query only the first post -->
   <?php $cat4 = new WP_Query('cat=4&showposts=1');
      if($cat4->have_posts()) : while($cat4->have_posts()) : $cat4->the_post(); ?>
      <!-- First post only content area -->
      <div class="first_post">

                <?php
                $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($image_id);
                if ($image_url) {
                 ?>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $image_url; ?>&w=196&h=115&q=1000" alt="<?php the_title();?>" /> 
                <!--  // Add timthumb to post featured image -->
                <?php } else { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/no-image.jpg'; ?>" alt="No image available" class="panikosule" />
                <?php } ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

      </div><!-- //first_post -->

      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
      <!-- Query the rest posts. Offset = -1 from the above  -->
      <?php $sidecat4 = new WP_Query('cat=4&showposts=2&offset=1');
      if($sidecat4->have_posts()) : while($sidecat4->have_posts()) : $sidecat4->the_post(); ?>
       <!-- Rest posts content area -->
     <div class="rest_post">

      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <?php the_title() ?>
       </a>

        </div><!-- //rest_posts  -->
      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
      <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().?>
    </div><!-- //categorys_box-->
```