# what is the difference between timthumb and post thumbnail?

Tags: post-thumbnails, timthumb

I get the image through wordpress built in post_thumbnail, but i see a lot of developers use timthumb for that and i don't know why! is it more flexible or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons:

1. post_thumbnail was introduced with WordPress 2.9, and many themes which used TimThumb because post_thumbnail wasn't yet available to them.
2. TimThumb is more flexible than post_thumbnail — it [gives you more options for how images are cropped](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/08/timthumb-part-4-moving-crop-location/), and [allows for simple filters to be applied](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/08/timthumb-image-filters/) to the images.

However, [TimThumb has also caused security issues](http://www.exploit-db.com/wordpress-timthumb-exploitation/), especially with sites which didn't keep their themes (and because of this their timthumb versions) up to date. Because of this, it often makes more sense to use post-thumbnail, especially if you don't need much beyond WordPress' built-in cropping for thumbnails.

Comment: I have a question: post_thumbnail doesn't work with already existed images, so i have to tell the user to setup the regenerate thumbnail plugin to regenerate the thumbnails, do i have to do that with timthumb too? does it work with already existed images?

Comment: @Elshereef & Gavin, see [kaiser](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69627/12615) and [Otto](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-image-resizer/) solutions to deal with Dynamic Images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is more flexible. It allows you to resize or crop image in way you want ( check it's parameter listing: http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2012/02/complete-timthumb-parameters-guide/ ). And have a look at project's homepage also: http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/

On the other side, if you do not need to use advanced image manipulation's, WordPress feature image (post_thumbnail) is OK. I, personally, have never uset timthumb in my themes and they all are working good. Especially when you can [add_image_size](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

Comment: Thanks a lot it seems that post_thumbnail is enough for me, Thanks again for your help.